# In JMeter when I try to pass a value using JSON Extractor only the default value is passed

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, extractor

My JMeter script seems to only want to pass the default value from the JSON Extractor to the next call.  I think the issue maybe with my expression. 
[image: Extractor]

[image: Testplan]

Response JSON looks like this:

```
{"userAssociations":[{"id":"1","userAssociationRole":"ACCOUNTHOLDER","userAssociationMechanism":"USER-DATAENTRY","userAssociationStatus":"ACTIVE","accountHolderAssociationStatus":"ACTIVE","accountHolder":{"id":"2","givenName":"Perf","familyName":"Test1"},"issuer":{"id":"1","name":"A College","localeId":"en-US"}}],"operation":{"result":"OK","errors":[],"requestTimeStampUtc":"2017-09-27T21:32:59.327Z","responseTimeStampUtc":"2017-09-27T21:32:59.345Z"}}
```

The idea here is that I want the second "id" =2 to be passed in the URL of the next call.  However I have only been able to get the default value to pass to the next call as a variable.

Comment: JMeter is version 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON Path should be:

> $.userAssociations[0].accountHolder.id

And Match N° should be 1

See:

[image]

Comment: Ah that combo worked.  Setting Match No to 1 and path to $.userAssociations[0].accountHolder.id .  Nice thank you.

Comment: Ichanged your json path expression, please check again, I tested and I am able to extract 2